# How to remove case sensitivity in the filter expression of a request?

Tags: fetch

Trying to fetch data from the C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake, but the request won't return anything if you do not match the case for a field exactly.

For example, this request does not fetch anything:

```
url = "https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/linelistrecord/fetch"

fetch_spec = {
  "spec": {
    "limit": 500,
    "filter": "contains(location.id, 'california')"
  }
}
```

Is there an easy to make this work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `lowerCase(str)` function which you may be able to use:

```
fetch_spec = {
  "spec": {
    "limit": 500,
    "filter": "contains(lowerCase(location.id), 'california')"
  }
}
```

However, this may result in reduced performance because location is indexed on the id field (primary key) and applying a function on it likely results in the underlying index to be not useable. I am purely speculating based on my own background knowledge of RDBMS.